# extracting data from an interactive form

Tags: pdf, forms

I am currently creating a fillable PDF - Form for a survey (I know, there are more convenient ways...).
I wonder wether there is an option to make the participants' data available for further analysis, for example a button that creates an .xml - file with containing the relevant data. The often referred to 'submit' - Button does not serve my needs as my mail provider is not supporting IMAP.
Hope my question is concise enough.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!? Where comes LaTeX into this question? Are you using `hyperref` to create the form?

Comment: Sorry for not pointing that out: 
I use LaTeX to create the document. Also, I use `hyperref` to create the radioButtons etc. . I thought about a button (similar to the 'submit' - button) that by clicking emits a file, in which the values of the different elements of the forms are listed (as stated above, the 'submit' - action is not an option for me). 
My question is, wether something like this would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the Submit action, but you can set a (Acrobat) JavaScript action using

```
this.exportAsXFDF() ;
```

which would export a data file with field name/field value pairs, in XML format. XFDF is the XML representation of the PDF-native FDF, Forms Data Format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried adding the Javascript action to my document. In Adobe Acrobat Reader XI, this doesn't work: 

`\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}   
\usepackage{insdljs}   
\begin{insDLJS}[H]{H}{J}   
function h() {this.exportAsXFDF(); }   
\end{insDLJS}   
\begin{document}   
\begin{Form}[action=mailto:forms@me?subject={Hello there},method=post]    
\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=X]{G:}{M=M,F=F}\\[1mm]    
\PushButton[name=myButton,onclick={h();}]{E}    
\end{Form}    
\end{document}` 

Could it be that this option ist not available in Adobe Reader XI?

Comment: sorry for the messy code.I tried quite hard to include linebreaks but it didn't work. Is there any source where this is explained?

Comment: This is not PDF (or would I expect something different)?

Comment: Yes, the code is compiled via TexStudio and the resulting document saved as .pdf .  It is thought to be viewed with adobe acrobat reader.

Comment: Then you have to set up your TexStudio file so that the export button has the above mentioned JavaScript action in the mouseUp event.

Comment: Hi Max, would you be able to post a MWE with this? It's not clear how to add it as a form action.

Comment: @MaxWyss do you say like [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25652144/)?